# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor - What does @* do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, shortcut

Since it's pretty difficult to search Google for punctuation...

I know in Razor that `@` starts a code block, but what does `@*` do? As far as I can tell in VS, it starts a comment block. If that's different from `/*`, how?

Comment: `@:` is not pre-encoded HTML. It's an indication to the Razor parser to switch to markup mode until the next new line character that's encountered within a markup context.

Comment: @marcind I mispoke; question modified to reflect that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@* is a server side comment:

If you have code like this:

```
<p>
   /* comment 1 */
   @* comment 2 *@
   <!-- comment 3 --> 
   @{ /* comment 4 */ }
</p>
```

comment 1 will not work, because you are not in server mode. That code will be send to the browser, and the browser will show it, because /* is not an html comment.

Also comment 3 will be sent to the client. And I even think, it will be parsed and executed on the server if it contains @ blocks.

Comment 2 and 4 will not be send over the line. but Nr 4 is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

From:
http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax

For ASP.NET Razor comments, you start the comment with @* and end it with *@. The comment can be on one line or multiple lines.

And if I understand you correctly the `/*` only applies from within a `<% %>` block because `/* */` is C# syntax for a comment. You can write `@*` from outside a `<% %>` block.
So instead of writing comments like

```
<% /* This is
a multiline comment */ %>
```

It can be written as:

```
@* This is
a multiline comment *@
```

Comment: +1, but /* still works inside of a @{} block (Razor, of course, doesn't use <% %>.)